# {'s': 'error', 'errmsg': 'Invalid request.from & to : Not Numeric'} , this is the error i am getting , how to solve this?

Tags: python

```
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
def datetotimestamp(datetime):
    time_tuple = datetime.timetuple()
    timestamp = round(time.mktime(time_tuple))
    return timestamp

start = datetotimestamp(datetime(2022,5,24))
end = datetotimestamp(datetime.today())
url = "https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/techCharts/indianMarket/stock/history?symbol=RELIANCE&resolution=5&from='+str(start)+&to=+str(end)+"

resp = requests.get(url).json()
print(resp)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error in your post.

Comment: the issue is almost-certainly that your URL isn't being constructed properly! for example, you just embed the string `='+str(start)+&to=+str(end)+` at the end of the URL, when these look like they should be parameters

Comment: I noticed you have ```str(end)``` and ```str(start)``` within the quotes.  Shouldn't those be outside the quotes?  i.e. ```...from=" + str(start) + ''&to=" + str(end)```?

Comment: What does this code do? Please be more specific. Maybe include a short one or two sentence introduction to the problem. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Adding `print(url)` to your code should explain everything.

Comment: Can you add details on where can we find documentation for priceapi.moneycontrol.com paid or free?

Answer (score 1):

Your url variable is ill-defined.

Use a f-string:

```
url = f"https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/techCharts/indianMarket/stock/history?symbol=RELIANCE&resolution=5&from={start}&to={end}"
```

Output:

```
'https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/techCharts/indianMarket/stock/history?symbol=RELIANCE&resolution=5&from=1653350400&to=1653528774'
```

Answer (score 0):

url is incorrect format

```
import requests 
import time 
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime 

def datetotimestamp(datetime): 
    time_tuple = datetime.timetuple() 
    timestamp = round(time.mktime(time_tuple)) 
    return timestamp

start = datetotimestamp(datetime(2022,5,24)) 
end = datetotimestamp(datetime.today()) 
url = "https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/techCharts/indianMarket/stock/history?symbol=RELIANCE&resolution=5&from={}&to={}".format(start, end)

resp = requests.get(url).json()
print(resp.content)
```